# Elasticsearch - Limit of total fields [1000] in index exceeded

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I saw that there are some concerns to raising the total limit on fields above 1000.
I have a situation where I am not sure how to approach it from the design point of view.
I have lots of  simple key value pairs:

```
key1:15, key2:45, key99999:1313123.
```

Where key is a string and value is a integer on which I would like to sort my results upon on where as if a certain document receives a key it gets sorted by the value.

I ended up creating an object and just put the key value pairs inside so I can match it easy.
For example I have sorting: "object.key".

I was wondering if I just use a simple object with bunch of strings inside that are just there for exact matching should I worry about raising this limit to 10k, or 20k.

Because I now have an issue where there can be more then 1k of these records. I've found I could use nested sorting but it still has a default limit of 10k.
Is there a good design pattern approach for this or should I not be worried by raising the field limits?

Simplified version of the query:

```
 GET products/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "sort": [
        {
          "sortingObject.someSortingKey1": {
            "order": "desc",
            "missing": 2,
            "unmapped_type":"float"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Point is that I get the sortingKey from request and I use it to sort my results. There are 100k different ways to sort the result for example

Answer (score 0):

There were some recent improvements (in 7.16) that should help there, but 10K or 20K fields is still a lot of overhead.

I'm not sure what kind of queries you need to run on those keyX fields, but maybe the flattened data-type would work for you? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/flattened.html

Comment: I am aware of flattened data types, but I don't think they will come in handy here is because I have to sort the data.
If I have Key1,2,3,4,.....n all of them have a numeric value which I sort upon on.

Say I have 3 documents: A,B,C

Document A has: key1:8, key2:7, key999:129
Document B has: key1:6, key2:1, key923:1150
Document C has: key1:2, key2:6, key999:130

Sending key1 would return A,B,C
key 2: A,C,B
key923: would return B, and other two randomly or whichever one comes first based on some other criterias

Comment: It's kind of a keyword field and you can sort on that. Did you try it and run into any issues?

Comment: Here issue is i need to match on a key that is dynamic, and sort on its value, I didnt know how to utilize flattened properly in that case

Comment: Can you add the query that you're trying to run to the initial question? That should make it a bit clearer

Comment: Done, please take a look :)